# Lost Source Code of a Batch file that I had eventually converted to an EXE. Anyway to get the source back?

Tags: batch-file, type-conversion, exe

I was working on a little Batch file script that I had converted into an EXE. I had then lost the batch file but I still have the EXE. Is there a way I can convert it back into a .bat file to get my source code back?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you used to convert the script, but 99% of the time, the script gets extracted to a folder in `%TEMP%`. Sometimes it's a hidden folder.

Comment: First delete all files and folders in the folder `%TEMP%` not currently in use by a running process. Then run the executable extracting the batch file script into `%TEMP%` folder or a subfolder for being processed by `cmd.exe` and press __Ctrl+C__. `cmd.exe` prompts you if batch job should be terminated. That gives you unlimited time to use Windows File Explorer or any other file manager or one more `cmd.exe` instance (command prompt) to look on the files in `%TEMP%` folder. One of them is the batch file which you need to restore.

Answer (score 4):

All batch "compilers" are just wrappers for the script that extract them to some directory (usually `%TEMP%`) and run them. The location in `%TEMP%` is going to vary by which compiler was used, but here are some of the more common ones and where the script ends up getting extracted:

For all of these, my initial script was called `raw_script.bat`.

| Compiler Name | Location | Hidden Folder? | My Script's Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Advanced BAT-to-EXE Converter | `%TEMP%\<string>\tmp<numbers>.bat` | Yes | `%TEMP%\wxy\tmp94807.bat` |
| f2ko Bat To Exe | `%TEMP%\<string>.tmp\<string>.tmp\<string>.bat` | No | `%TEMP%\3F11.tmp\3F12.tmp\3F13.bat` |
| Slimm Bat To Exe | `%TEMP%\<string>.bat` | No | `%TEMP%\it.bat` |
| BlackHost Bat to Exe | `%TEMP%\<string>.bat` | No | `%TEMP%\cmd.bat` |
| Gotek BatchCompiler | `%TEMP%\<string>\tmp<numbers>.bat` | Yes | `%TEMP%\ytmp\tmp57317.bat` |
| Bat2Exe.net | `%TEMP%\<string>.tmp\<filename>.bat` | No | `%TEMP%\7zS1034.tmp\raw_script.bat` |
| IExpress | `%TEMP%\<string>.tmp\<filename>.bat` | No | `%TEMP%\IXP000.tmp\raw_script.bat` |

You may have also used some other compiler that does not extract to `%TEMP%`, and as long as the script takes input from a `set /p` command that's later used in an `if` statement and that variable doesn't use delayed expansion, you can use code injection to extract the text of the script:

```
"=="" call type %0 >"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\output.txt" & REM
```

It's `REM`  and not `REM`. Note the space at the end.

If that crashes the script, the `if` statement may not use quotes. If that's the case, use

```
""=="" call type %0 >"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\output.txt" & REM
```

instead. Same code as before, just with an extra `"` at the beginning.